# How to set value to iframe in html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

```
    Is it possible to set value as attribute to iframe in HTML? Or is there any other solution?



<iframe name="some name" src="url" value="some values"></iframe>
```

JS code

i am accessing attribute using JavaScript like

```
parent.window.frames[window.name].name;
```

I got name properly but value not getting.

```
            if possible then how to access??
```

Comment: Why do you need a value attribute for iframe?

Answer (score 0):

`window.frames[window.name]` refers to the `window` object within `iframe`, not the `iframe` element on main page. If you need to refer an attribute set to `iframe` from inside of iframe, you can get it like so:

```
var value = window.frameElement.getAttribute('value');
```

In case of `iframe` `value` is a custom attribute, hence it's not reflected to `value` property. Instead of custom attributes I'd suggest you to use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: @Ravi Chothe Any comments?